# What does the 'Failed to move application. Not enough memory' error mean when choosing 'Move to SD card'?

Tags: sd-card, 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, app2sd

When I choose 'Settings - Applications - Manage applications' , and a 'Move to SD card' I get the 'Failed to move application. Not enough memory' error.

Anyone know why ?

I am running Froyo 2.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S phone.

I have 1.7GB free of system memory and 13.1 GB internal memory free on the internal SD card.

**UPDATE **

**Can someone with an Galaxy S phone please confirm this ? I have seen it on two phones, and really would like to know what's happening here.**

Comment: I've only had it say this when my SD card is full

Comment: @Bryan Denny: As I would expect. But both me and my colleague (who also has s Samsung Galaxy S phone) receive this message. You don't have to format an internal SD card, do you ? Or make it available in any other way ?

Comment: The Galaxy S phones have three sets of memory, System Memory, Internal SD card, and External SD card (if plugged in), have you checked the free memory on both SD card memories?

Comment: @GAThrawn: no external SD card ( no slot as far as I can see ), internal SD card 13.43 GB , 13.09 Free and internal phone storage Available space 1.71 GB. The Internal SD card has a section : Format SD card' with underneath 'Format (erase) the SD card'

Comment: Assuming you've got a standard Galaxy S, and not one of the US variants the external SD card slot is under the back cover right beside the SIM card. As far as I know all Galaxy S variants have an external SD slot, just don't know where it is on the variants.

Comment: @GAThrawn: You are correct. I thought an external SD card meant that an external slot was visible and available. Indeed, one is underneath the back cover. Still doesn't explain why I get the not enough memory error, though.

Comment: Hy see if you have microsd card in your phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem with leaked 2.2 Galaxy S Vibrant software (happened to me).  Even if you're not using a Vibrant I would suspect the issue is the same, since the software is mostly the same.

You can fix it using [this post at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9327204&postcount=1) if you have a Vibrant or i9000.  If you have another model just check the subforum for your device (or take a risk and try this anyways).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out .. will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same message on unrooted android 4.0.4, Alcatel 992D, with 12G free space on SD card. I am posting here, cos maybe it helps on 2.2, as well.

Installed AppMgr III, 3.10 (App 2 SD), and it also listed the same apps as movable, were not even marked with the gray X (supposed to tell you that by moving app you will lose some functionality, e.g. widget stops working on main screen).

It seems that only those apps gave me this message when trying to move (via AppMgr AND via the built in option in android) which came pre-installed on the phone.

Below article says moving/deleting pre-installed apps is not possible on unrooted phone: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82517.aspx

It seems likely to me that in this case, the option "move to SD Card" not being grayed out is the bug, and maybe AppMgr receiving this misleading data causes it to show them as moveable, as well, while the inability to move them is by design.

Answer (score 0):

For people that have this problem in the future. It is an ODEX issue. Some unused thing in there is causing it to think space is all eaten up. Find an app that cleans ODEX files. Chances are you are rooted which allows apps that mess with the ODEX files to screw stuff up by accident.

Comment: Good answer, but do you have any recommendation for an app that cleans odex files? Please edit it into your answer. :)