# Galaxy S and Skype - Why am I getting an "Insufficient memory" error?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, skype, insufficient-memory

Galaxy S running 2.2.  try to install SKYPE but get the error - "insufficient memory" when there is loads on the phone and i can install any other app quite normally.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: What model do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing Skype installs to the SD card by default, in which case you should check out this question: [What does the 'Failed to move application. Not enough memory' error mean when choosing 'Move to SD card'?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/what-does-the-failed-to-move-application-not-enough-memory-error-means-when-ch)